# how to access the data of a GStreamer buffer in Python?

Tags: python, gstreamer

In the old (pre-GObject-introspection) GStreamer bindings, it was possible to access `gst.Buffer` data via the `.data` attribute or by casting to `str`. This is no longer possible:

```
>>> p buf.data
*** AttributeError: 'Buffer' object has no attribute 'data'
>>> str(buf)
'<GstBuffer at 0x7fca2c7c2950>'
```

Answer (score 7):

To access the contents of a `Gst.Buffer` in recent versions, you must first `map()` the buffer to get a `Gst.MapInfo`, which has a `data` attribute of type `bytes` (`str` in Python 2).

```
(result, mapinfo) = buf.map(Gst.MapFlags.READ)
assert result

try:
    # use mapinfo.data here
    pass
finally:
    buf.unmap(mapinfo)
```

You can also access the buffer's constituent `Gst.Memory` elements with `get_memory()`, and map them individually. (AFAICT, calling `Buffer.map()` is equivalent to calling `.get_all_memory()` and mapping the resulting `Memory`.)

Unfortunately, writing to these buffers is not possible since Python represents them with immutable types even when the `Gst.MapFlags.WRITE` flag is set. Instead, you'd have to do something like create a new `Gst.Memory` with the modified data, and use `Gst.Buffer.replace_all_memory()`.

Comment: If you are targeting CentOS 7, there is no such method in the inadequate gi bindings that ship with it, but there is a workaround as documented here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678663#c73