# Modify a buffer in Python Gstreamer 1.14.5 using custom plugin

Tags: c++, python-3.x, buffer, gstreamer, nvidia-deepstream

I am using Gstreamer 1.14.5 with its Python bindings. I'm looking to remove custom RTP Header Extensions from an RTSP stream. Hence I need to open each packet, see if the X bit is set, and if so remove some part of the buffer.

This should be doable in a custom plugin using either the transform or transform_ip methods. As Python represents the buffers as immutable types ([how to access the data of a GStreamer buffer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773551/how-to-access-the-data-of-a-gstreamer-buffer-in-python)), I'm using ctypes to attempt to access the memory underneath (https://lifestyletransfer.com/how-to-make-gstreamer-buffer-writable-in-python/)

I have found that while the above tutorial works for creating a new buffer and modifying it, it doesn't work in the Python Gstreamer pipeline using a custom plugin (GstRemoveHeaderExtensions):

```
"( rtspsrc location={} name=source latency=50 ! GstRemoveHeaderExtensions ! rtph264depay name=depay ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96".format(self.source_url))
```

in GstRemoveHeaderExtensions we see an error on the line:

```
with map_gst_buffer(buf, Gst.MapFlags.READ | Gst.MapFlags.WRITE) as mapped:
```

```
raise ValueError("Writable array requested but buffer is not writeable")
```

Perhaps transform_ip creates or modifies a buffer in a different way? Either way is it possible to make them accessible during execution of the pipeline?

Possibly relevant. Using:

```
sys.getrefcount(pbuffer)
```

We see ref count is 5.